# PropertyInfo.GetProperty returns null when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, properties, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get the value of a private property of a WPF WebBrowser object. I can see in the debugger that it has a non-null value.

```
PropertyInfo activeXProp = Browser.GetType().GetProperty("ActiveXInstance", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object activeX = activeXProp.GetValue(Browser, null); // here I get null for the activeX value
activeX.GetType().GetProperty("Silent").SetValue(activeX, true); // and here it crashes for calling a method on a null reference...
```

My guess is I'm not using reflection in a proper way, but what is the proper way to do it in this case?
The project is a WPF project running on .NET 4.6.1 and Windows 10.
I tried running it with admin rights (adding a manifest file to the project), but made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure that `activeX` is `null`? It does not give me null.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. Unfortunately it really does give me a null value. Here's the full project if you want to check: https://github.com/zskolbay/WpfBrowserTest

Comment: I tested your code on github, `activeX` is not null. Only the next line throws an exception.

Comment: It is `activeX.GetType().GetProperty("Silent")` that return `null`.

Comment: If it's really `activeX` being null, it's null when no window is created and you try to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type returned by `activeX.GetType()` is *System.__ComObject*, which doesn't support this kind of reflection. However, there are two easy solutions.

**Using `dynamic`**

```
dynamic activeX = activeXProp.GetValue(Browser, null);
activeX.Silent = true;
```

`dynamic` supports all types of COM reflection, provided by the *IDispatch* COM interface (implemented by all ActiveX elements).

**Just reflection**

A small change to your code does the same as the code above:

```
object activeX = activeXProp.GetValue(Browser, null);
activeX.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, activeX, new object[]{true});
```

Both methods invoke the same thing on the object, but I guess the first one is faster over time due to caching of the call site. Use the second one only if you cannot use `dynamic` for some reason.